# Adding a row (header) to a numpy matrix issue using np.vstack in python

Tags: python, matrix, numpy

I have a numpy matrix like this:

```
>>> matrix
[['M' 'G' 'H' 'H' 'H' 'H' 'H' 'H' 'S' 'H' 'M' 'A' 'A' 'A' 'M']
 ['A' 'A' 'T' 'E' 'D' 'D' 'I' 'R' 'G' 'Q' 'L' 'Q' 'S' 'H' 'G']]
```

I want to add a new row to this matrix and I proceed like this:

```
length_seqs = matrix.shape[1]
header = np.arange(length_seqs)

matrix_with_header = np.vstack((header,matrix))
```

But when I print this new matrix it appears the following:

```
>>> print matrix_with_header
[['0' '1' '2' '3' '4' '5' '6' '7' '8' '9' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1']
 ['M' 'G' 'H' 'H' 'H' 'H' 'H' 'H' 'S' 'H' 'M' 'A' 'A' 'A' 'M']
 ['A' 'A' 'T' 'E' 'D' 'D' 'I' 'R' 'G' 'Q' 'L' 'Q' 'S' 'H' 'G']]
```

As you can see, when a more than one digit number is need to be printed, it doesn't and only shows the first digit. Any explanation and solution to this?? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you want to be using a `matrix` instead of an `array` if you're not using them as actual matrices?

Comment: the code which follow this one the matrix is needed... but you're right.. if I just need to print the matrix I could use an array instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dtype` of your matrix is probably `'S1'` which means that everything is a 1-char long string.  Change it to `'S2'` to allow longer strings.

For example:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.array(['hi','hello'])

In [3]: a.dtype
Out[3]: dtype('|S5')

In [4]: a = np.array(['hi','hello'], dtype='S2')

In [5]: a
Out[5]: 
array(['hi', 'he'], 
      dtype='|S2')
```